# Pod with a single container and multiple images

Tags: kubernetes

How to Create a pod named pod1 with a single app container for each of the following images running inside one container Redis + Nginx + busybox.

- Can some answer this question?
- Is this possible to create in
  Kubernetes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Can some answer this question? => Yes
- Is this possible to create in Kubernetes? => Yes

---

> First way (not recommended)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: po-with-multiple-container
spec:
  containers:
  - image: redis:5.0.4
    name: redis-container

  - image: nginx:latest
    name: webserver-container
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80

  - image: busybox
    name: busybox-container
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
```

---

> Second Way - recommended way

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: po-with-multiple-container
spec:
  containers:
    - image: redis:5.0.4
      name: redis-container
 
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: po-with-multiple-container
spec:
  containers:
    - image: nginx:latest
      name: webserver-container
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: po-with-multiple-container
spec:
  containers:
    - image: busybox
      name: busybox-container
      command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
      args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
```