# Multiple containers inside one pod using oc new-app - Openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

This thread shows multiple containers can be created using YAML configuration, creating one Pod with multiple containers inside: [Create a pod with a single app container with multiple images in kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67082250/create-a-pod-with-a-single-app-container-with-multiple-images-in-kubernetes-clus)

Does the `oc new-app` have this functionality too? Are there any any other CLI oc tools which would allow this function?

Comment: Is something blocked you to use oc create -f your_deployment.yaml where you could configure multiple containers include init containers too ?

Comment: Well for some reason one of the containers I'm deploying only works if deployed using `oc new-app`, and attempts at deploying it through a yaml config, or the GUI Add+ -> container-image, both seem to kill the container at a certain point within its startup.
So it seems `oc new-app` is doing something the other two aren't, however I thought it should have a multi-container feature...

Comment: In that case try to look at what is generated on the oc client side, oc new-app ... --dry-run=client -o json > deployment.yaml

Comment: Thanks for this - I've realised the container was not starting due to resources issues in the end, and there's not actually a difference between the two ways of deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that `oc new-app` does not let you create a Pod with multiple container images as far as I can see.

User "bodo" above had the right idea I think. You can use the following command to generate the YAML file and then edit that YAML to add more containers to the Pod:

```
oc new-app --name my-application --docker-image=example.com/repository/myimage:latest --dry-run=true -o yaml
```

Comment: Thanks (and to @bodo) this is super useful - I will stick with a YAML deployment since that's all we have available, but this make it easy to get a yaml config quickly

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. Check the documentation from [here](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/dev_guide/new_app.html#grouping-images-and-source-in-a-single-pod).

Comment: It looks like this documentation should work... but it's not finding the image:
`oc new-app \
    dyno1~"v1r3n/dynomite" \
    es~"docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.15" \
    --group=dyno1+es`
Does this not look right?